# MIPS Help: Adding arrays and printing their sum

Tags: arrays, sum, mips

Add Two Arrays:
Write a MIPS assembly language program that adds two arrays (element-by-element addition) and
prints their sum.

Print out the element of the sum in a single line, labeled and with values separated by spaces.
The line should be terminated by a \n" character. For instance, if the arrays a and b are as above,
the output will look like:
The sum is: 1 4 7 6 10 14 11 16 21 16

Here's the code I have so far

```
# data segment

.data




size:    .word  10 #Size of first array
$a0:    .word  2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20 #First array's elements
size2:   .word 10 #Size of second array
$a1:   .word -1, 0, 1, -2, 0, 2, -3, 0, 3, -4 #Second array's elements
size3:   .word 10 #size of third array

main:

la   $t0, $a0   #$t0 points to $a0[0]          
lw   $t1, size   #$t1 equals number of elements in $a0[]  
la   $t2, $a1  #$t2 points to $a1[0] 
lw   $t3, size2  #$t3 equals number of elements in $a1[]


la $t4, $a0 #load base address of array into register $t4
la $t5,  #load base address of array into register $t5


Assigning the array's elements to temp variables:

lw $t6,0($a0)

addiu $a0,$a0,4

lw $t7,0($a0)

addiu $a0,$a0,4

lw $t8,0($a0)

addiu $a0,$a0,4

lw $t9,0($a0)

addiu $a0,$a0,4

lw $t10,0($a0)

addiu $a0,$a0,4






# exit program:

li   $v0, 10      # terminate program
syscall
```

so here's where I am stumped. How do I go about putting every element of both the first and second arrays into MIPS values like `$t0`, `$t1`, etc.

and then how do I go about adding them together and printing out the sum of the arrays?

I'm sorry to take up your time but I have searched for hours for a guide on how to add arrays in MIPS and then print the sum, to no avail

Comment: `lw $t6, 0(list)` is not a valid instruction (unless your assembler transforms it into `lw $t6,list($zero)`, which still could be invalid depending on the address of `list`). The base address (i.e. the thing you put between the parentheses) should be a register. You should probably review the basics of MIPS assembly programming before you continue with this assignment.

Comment: *"You should probably review the basics of MIPS assembly programming"* This. I would say even (re)view computer and CPU architecture.

Answer (score 1):

You would use [a MIPS instruction set reference](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html) to check which instruction is appropriate for each step of the program.

For example, to load a 32-bit word into `$t0` from the address given in `$a0` you would use `lw $t0,0($a0)`.

To increase `$a0` to point at the next word you would use `addiu $a0,$a0,4`.

To branch to a label if two values (like, say, a counter and the array length) aren't equal you would use something like `bne $t2,$a1,some_label`.

And so on..

By the way, I'm not sure what `$b0` and `$b1` are supposed to be. DId you mean `$t0` and `$t1`?

Comment: edited it with your suggested changes (didn't write out the whole part, wanted to make sure I was doing it correctly). Is this what you meant? And your example variables threw me off a bit. Could you help me see what you meant by $a0? Is $a0 my "list" value, or an entirely new value I need to declare? And out of curiosity instead of using addiu $a0, $a0, 4 could I use lw $t1, 4($a0)?

Comment: @ErichHarkema Hmmm $a0 is not a variable but a CPU registers. This is no PHP... There are no "variables" properly speaking in assembly. About your second question: no, those instructions have nothing in common: `addiu` is to add 2 registers, `lw` is to load a value from memory into a register. It looks like you don't quite understand what you're doing. I suggest you to read [this tutorial](http://chortle.ccsu.edu/AssemblyTutorial/index.html).

Comment: Like @m0skit0 said, `$a0` is one of the [CPU registers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253512(v=vs.80).aspx). In the original code you had posted you had put the address of one of the arrays in `$a0`, so I used that as an example. It's up to you which registers you want to use. As for `lw $t1,4($a0)`, that would not be the appropriate instruction to use. `lw $t1,4($a0)` loads a word from the address `($a0 + 4)` into `$t1` - while `addiu $a0,$a0,4` adds 4 to `$a0`.

Comment: @Michael I adjusted it, is that a proper register for lw $t10,0($a0)?

Comment: @ErichHarkema your question does not make much sense, and besides there's no `$t10` register. This really is not a place where to learn assembly from scratch, but for specific questions. IMHO you're far from understanding any of the things Michael is telling you. I strongly suggest you check the link I gave you above and come back with specific questions. Sorry for being such a killjoy.